# Converter para cores hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, cores

Quero colocar dentro de um array, as cores hexadecimais dívidas a partir de uma variável, assim tenho as cores todas diferentes dentro do array.

Tenho o seguinte exemplo, mas ao utilizar as cores não funciona:

```
        var color=[];
        var n_elements =10 ;
        var inc=0;
        //65535 número maximo
        var step=parseInt(65535/n_elements);//#FFFFFF


        for(i=0;i<=65535;i+=step){
            var hexString = i.toString(16);
            color[inc]="#"+hexString;

            console.log(color[inc]);
            inc++;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, você deveria usar `16777216` (`256 * 256 * 256` - Vermelho x Verde x Azul) em vez de `65535` (`256 * 256` - faltou um). Em segundo, é necessário preencher o resultado com zeros à esquerda, caso o resultado final seja menor que `0x100000`:

```js
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5]; // Exemplo


        var color=[];
        var n_elements = data.length ;
        var inc=0;
        var step=parseInt(16777216/n_elements);//#FFFFFF


        for(i=0;i<=16777216;i+=step){
            var hexString = i.toString(16);
          
            var pad = "000000";
            color[inc]="#"+(pad + hexString).slice(-6);

            document.body.innerHTML += (color[inc]) + "<br/>";
            inc++;
        }
```